# How to convert SQL statment to GetItemLinqQueryable in C# with cosmosdb SDK v3

Tags: c#, pagination, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How do I convert this cosmosbd sql string `"SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c"` to use it with  `GetItemLinqQueryable` method. Basically I want to return total number of items in container.

I'm trying to build generic pagination for my apis. Therefore I need to know total count of items (including all `WHERE` statement) in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [download my demo](https://github.com/Jason446620/cosmos-dotnet-query) from github.

The effect in my screenshot is that you should be what you want, please let me know if you need additional help.

[image]

*Include `where`*

[image]

```
            Console.WriteLine("Beginning operations...\n");
            CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient("https://localhost:8081/", "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==");
            Database database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("ToDoList");
            Container container = database.GetContainer("jason");
            // Query for an item
            FeedIterator <dynamic> feedIterator =  container.GetItemQueryIterator<dynamic>("SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c");
            while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                FeedResponse<dynamic> response = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync();
                foreach (var item in response)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }
```

Comment: The answer is not quite what I've expected. However I'll give it an accepted answer because of this line `FeedIterator <dynamic> feedIterator =  container.GetItemQueryIterator<dynamic>("SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c");`. Basically I did not know one can pass `sql` string to `GetItemQueryIterator` with type `dynamic`.

Comment: @LordZed You are so nice. Anything else that needs help, I'll be happy to help you.